# Cannot create Digital watch face in Android Studio 3.5

Tags: android, wear-os, watchface

I am running Android Studio 3.5 on Windows 10.  I want to create a new Wear OS Digital watch face.  I select "Start a new Android Studio project", "Wear OS", "Watch Face", Next, and fill in all the fields.  There used to be a drop down for Analog or Digital but I no longer see it.  If I pick Finish I get code for an Analog watch face.  Where did they put the selection for Analog or Digital?